# Coordinate Origin for SVG Symbol

Tags: svg

I would like to move a particular composite shape to a <Symbol> definition, and then re-use it. This helps make the SVG code neater, and provides some global control over the actual structure of that shape. The shape is symmetrical about a given mid-point; however, the x/y coordinates of subsequent <Use> statements need to reference the top-left corner rather than its natural original, and this means that all usage of the shape must be aware of its total size. Is there a way to position a Symbol by some origin other than its top-left corner?

Contrived example, purely to explain this better. The following concentric-circle Symbol has a natural origin. However, the subsequent Use statement has to offset its x/y coordinates by half the Symbol size in order to position it correctly (at 20,20 in this example). Ideally, the usage of the symbol should not have to know this information.

```
<defs>
  <symbol id="ex">
    <circle  fill="green" cx="8" cy="8" r="8"/>
    <circle  fill="white" cx="8" cy="8" r="6"/>
    <circle  fill="green" cx="8" cy="8" r="4"/>
  </symbol>
</defs>


<use xlink:href="#ex" x="12" y="12">
```

Comment: Where is your SVG markup?

Comment: It's a general question, not specific to any given shape

Comment: It would still help helping you. I'd have to try it out myself, but I don't want to spend my time building a test case on my own first.

Comment: Draw your symbol at the origin then. (cx, cy=0) Problem solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The downside to a symbol is that it cuts of rendering at the border of a viewport. (which is also an upside, since you can define a viewBox.) But you can avoid using it at all. Everything in a `<defs>` element is not rendered directly, so you can exchange the `<symbol>` for a `<g>` and center everything on the origin:

```
<defs>
  <g id="ex">
    <circle  fill="green" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
    <circle  fill="white" cx="0" cy="0" r="6"/>
    <circle  fill="green" cx="0" cy="0" r="4"/>
  </g>
</defs>

<use xlink:href="#ex" x="12" y="12">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nuzwn07n/

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question correctly, you want to be able to say

```
<use xlink:href="#ex" x="20" y="20">
```

..and then the circle symbol is positioned with its *center* at [20,20]. The solution I propose requires you to know the size of the symbol, but only once (in the `<symbol>` declaration), and not on every `<use>` element.

1: In the `<symbol>`, put everything in a group which you `translate` so the center of the graphics lies on the top-left corner.

```
<symbol id="ex">
    <g transform="translate(-8,-8)">
        <circle ...
    </g>
</symbol>
```

2: If you now `<use>` that symbol, you'll only see the quarter circle that's still within the symbol's "viewport". To display the whole circle, simply apply [`overflow="visible"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/overflow) to the `<symbol>`.

```
<symbol id="ex" overflow="visible">
    <g transform="translate(-8,-8)">
        <circle ...
    </g>
</symbol>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0ghucsrp/

Comment: overflow="visible" is a performance killer. Use a viewBox instead.

Comment: @RobertLongson - Interesting, would you mind updating the fiddle to show that approach?